# hide with window scroll not container scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, css-position

I've a tricky problem. So I have two fixed element with space in between under those two elements I have a relative positioned element, everything is ok so far. Now when I scroll the relative positioned element will scroll and appear in between the two fixed elements and on top of the first one, here is [the jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/IlATiyer/3/edit) to make it clearer. I'd like the relative positioned content not to appear when scroll, like if it was a box scrolling with an overflow hidden.

The goal is to do a kind of box scrolling but with a window scrolling.

I'd like a css solution but I'm also opened to any js solution.

Comment: Hey, your jsfiddle is actually a jsbin and I'm not seeing any "relatively" positioned elements in your bin. Did you link the correct thing?

Comment: So you would like the header to hide the scrolled content? You also spelled relative incorrectly in your bin =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

http://jsbin.com/uSEfUMA/2/edit

fixed has a background

you can also add padding to body if you don't want to set a background to fixed

Answer (score 1):

Could make a zindexed div with a background set to the same color as the page bg, put that over the relative positioned div and under the absolutes so when the relative div scrolls to that point of the page it appears to dissapear how I believe you want it to, or just use overflow hidden and absolute positioning to lock it into place and clip the content.